# Displaying mysql string outputs in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

Can anyone tell me how to display something like this in wordpress? I know the SQL code for it, just not how to display it in Wordpress. Ive tried to google plug ins etc with no luck.

[image: Dashboard example where mysql statement would display output]

Comment: How does it look like now in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `NUMBER_FORMAT` or `MONEY_FORMAT` functions of PHP and format your data before displaying it on page. You do not need to rely on sql.

[Number Format](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp)
[Money Format](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_money_format.asp)

If you insist using sql and try showing data as it comes from database you can query your data as shown below.

[FORMAT()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-format-function.php)

`CONCAT('$', FORMAT(VAL, 2))`

Comment: Thank you and then how do I integrate that display on WP? Custom HTML and try to call the .php file?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82542/currency-price-formating-on-custom-fields Here is another link for you. I am sure that there are many ways to implement this kind of problem into your php file custom or not. You should focus on php not sql in this case.

Comment: Edited my answer with sql scenario. Check it. @Bob

Comment: Thanks. I am struggling to figure out how to embed either/display either in WP

Comment: You only asked for an advice and this is what i can give you as your offerings. Share with us your code and what you have accomplished for now. Then maybe some of us help you in a better way. @Bob

Comment: Much appreciated but the question is displaying in wp. I cant take either of the above into WP without some interface which is what the question is?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite familiar with wordpress html editor but I think you can do something like this:

Make an `<input>` field with `text` type, remove the borders and set as read-only. Then send the value from sql query - make sure the value looked exactly as you want it - according to your example there, the value should be '$6,621,280'. Use that value to show in the `<input>` field.

Refer to this jsfiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/6vqhc1sL/3/